# python real-time client-server application

Tags: python, client-server, real-time

I need create a real-time client-server application (like Dropbox).

Client application should listen one channel of data.

I can do it with python?

What solutions, technologies, modules exists in python for this task?

Comment: Off-topic Question. BTW if you're interested in dropbox's stack, then check this out: http://highscalability.com/blog/2011/3/14/6-lessons-from-dropbox-one-million-files-saved-every-15-minu.html

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it with Python.  You could do it with PHP, Bash, JavaScript, Ruby, C, C++, C#, Java, Haskell, Go, Assembler, Perl, Pascal, Oberon, Prolog, Lisp, or Caml if you like too.

Most interfaces to sockets fall into one of two categories:

1. Blocking interfaces
2. Event interfaces

There is no way to know which is right for your application without knowing what your application does.